# AutoCompleteTextView: Filter results from a previously made list of suggestions

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am looking for a method for filtering results from a previously made list of suggestions. Currently, I have done this with a "AutoCompleteTextView", but it does not do exactly what I want. AutoCompleteTextView works with "strings begining with" and I want that it works with "string containing". I show below an exmaple of what I have and what I want:

---

[List of suggestions]
aaa, baa, caa, daa, ddd

---

[What happens when using AutoCompleteTextView]

User looks for "a" and appears as a suggestion: "aaa".

---

[What I want]

User looks for "a" and appears as a suggestion: "aaa", "baa", "caa", "daa".
The user continues typing and looks for "aa" and appears: "aaa", "baa", "caa", and "daa". The user continue typing and looks for "aaa" and only appears "aaa".

---

Any reference or documentation is enough, I am not looking for my work to be done by the community.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main point here is that you need to implement a customized `ArrayFilter` which uses `contains` together with/instead of `startsWith`.

I have an answer at the following question, please take a look:

[AutoCompleteTextView not completing words inside parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926034/autocompletetextview-not-completing-words-inside-parentheses)

Hope this helps!