# Android : AutoCompleteTextView not adding dot dot at end and increasing its size

Tags: java, android, user-interface, autocompletetextview

I am working on an Android project in which I am fetching addresses using Places API and displaying them using AutoCompleteTextView. Right now, it is working properly, but I want to add dot dot at the end of address, so it's not chopped.

I checked other SO links and changed some values in XML, but it is not working. Also, I would like to know what can I do to set the results to fit the width of the screen, the height seems okay.

Here is the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/login_travel_register"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="32dp"
    android:paddingLeft="20dp"
    android:paddingRight="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="32dp">


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/register_travel_transparent_background"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingLeft="30dp"
        android:paddingRight="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="22dp">
  <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center_vertical">

            <internetlegion.com.restaurantlunchify.Templates.MaterialDesignIconsTextView
                style="@style/TextViewAppearance.Title1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:padding="0dp"
                android:text="@string/material_icon_account"
                android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_300"
                android:textSize="22dp" />

            <AutoCompleteTextView
                android:id="@+id/restaurant_address_autocomplete"
                android:layout_width="270dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:singleLine="true"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:scrollHorizontally="true"
                android:background="@drawable/edit_text_background_accent"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Address"
                android:lineSpacingExtra="1dp"
                android:textColor="@color/main_color_grey_600"
                android:textCursorDrawable="@drawable/edit_text_cursor_drawable_main">
            </AutoCompleteTextView>

        </LinearLayout>
// Other fields and all
</All layout endings>
```

Here is how it looks right now :

[image]

Kindly let me know what I should do. Thank you.

*Edit*

The adapter code for AutoComplete :

```
  autoCompView.setAdapter(new GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(this, R.layout.search_list_item));
        //autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        autoCompView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                String selection = (String) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

                for (int i = 0; i < resultList.size(); i++) {
                    if (resultList.get(i).equals(selection)) {
                        String selectedAddress = (String) resultList.get(i);
                        String[] strings = selectedAddress.split(",");
                        if (strings.length > 2) {
                            autoCompView.setText(strings[0]);
                            restRestaurant.setRestaurantAddress(strings[0]);

                            restaurantCityField.setText(strings[1]);
                            restRestaurant.setCity(strings[1]);


                        } else {
                            autoCompView.setText(selectedAddress);
                            restRestaurant.setRestaurantAddress(selectedAddress);
                        }
                        autoCompView.requestFocus();
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        autoCompView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                autoCompView.requestFocus();
            }
        });



  class GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter implements Filterable {

        public GooglePlacesAutocompleteAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return resultList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public String getItem(int index) {
            return (String) resultList.get(index);
        }

        @Override
        public Filter getFilter() {
            return new Filter() {
                @Override
                protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
                    FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                    if (constraint != null) {
                        // Retrieve the autocomplete results.
                        resultList = autocomplete(constraint.toString());

                        // Assign the data to the FilterResults
                        filterResults.values = resultList;
                        filterResults.count = resultList.size();
                    }
                    return filterResults;
                }

                @Override
                protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
                    if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                        notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {
                        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
                    }
                }
            };

        }
    }
```

search_list_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: you need to ellipsize your drop-down list item, not ACTV itself

Comment: @pskink : What does that mean? How do I do that?

Comment: it depends on adapter you are using

Comment: @pskink : I have added the code of adapter and other in bottom of the main post. Can you please have a look.

Comment: so adding `elipsize` in `search_list_item` didn't work?

Comment: @pskink : Nope... It didnt work

Comment: does it change anything if you add `android:background` in that xml file? just for testing?

Comment: @pskink : What should I supply to background. Only android:background is not allowed.

Comment: android:background="#ddd" or "#d00" to make sure it is red

Comment: @pskink : When I do that, the text seems selected, like grayish... was that the intention? Lets go to chat.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100480/discussion-between-we-are-borg-and-pskink).

Answer (score 0):

You need to add  `android:ellipsize="end"` in search_list_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:ellipsize="end"
android:singleLine="true"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: Did that, nothing happened.

Comment: What's your full string ?

Comment: An address, like building name, street name, city, postal-code.

Comment: Your string exceeding the view?

Comment: Yes. THat is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Please use as the following:

listitem.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:scrollHorizontally="true"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceListItemSmall"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeightSmall" />
```

My code:

```
String[] myData = new String[]{"Africa (AF) Africa (AF) Africa (AF) Africa (AF)", "America (AFM)", "Apple (AMP)"};
AutoCompleteTextView text = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.first_state);
CustomArrayAdapter adapter = new CustomArrayAdapter(this, R.layout.listitem, myData);
```

Screenshot:

[image: BNK's screenshot]

Comment: I will try this and get back to you. Thanks a lot.. :-)

Comment: Actually, the xml's content in the answer of @ShoebSiddique works in my project too

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but you are using a CustomArrayAdapter. Can I know it's implementation, you can see the adapter I am using as results are retrieved using Google Places API.

Comment: Please read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926034/autocompletetextview-not-completing-words-inside-parentheses/32928446?s=0|5.2693#32928446 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33047156/how-to-create-custom-baseadapter-for-autocompletetextview too

Comment: That is because of your CustomArrayAdapter, replace that with the Google adapter that I have, and then can you let me know. Thank you,.

Comment: I don't think so, you can try a new sample project with CustomArrayAdapter

Comment: The same thing was suggested by pskink as well, and it worked, but not with the Google Adapter..

Comment: Ok, I will try tomorrow if I have free time

Comment: Sure. Thanks a lot. :-)