# Change AutoCompleteTextView filter from "startsWith" to "Contains"?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I would like to change the default filtering in `AutoCompleteTextView`. The default filtering finds all strings that startsWith the given token. My project requires that the filtering should find all strings that contains the given token.

Is it possible?

Comment: Pls read my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926034/autocompletetextview-not-completing-words-inside-parentheses/32928446#32928446

Comment: Take a look at this solution also: http://stackoverflow.com/a/37298258/1808829

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I found a solution for that, thanks to Google and searching for two days. As @torque203 suggested, I've implemented my own custom Adapter. First define a new XML file to custom Item in the adapter:

## autocomplete_item.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:text="Medium Text"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingTop="16dp"
        android:paddingBottom="16dp"
        android:id="@+id/lbl_name" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

---

Create new class for your Names:

## Names

```
public class Names {
    public String name;
}
```

---

## NamesAdapter

```
public class NamesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Names> {

    Context context;
    int resource, textViewResourceId;
    List<Names> items, tempItems, suggestions;

    public NamesAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<Names> items) {
        super(context, resource, textViewResourceId, items);
        this.context = context;
        this.resource = resource;
        this.textViewResourceId = textViewResourceId;
        this.items = items;
        tempItems = new ArrayList<Names>(items); // this makes the difference.
        suggestions = new ArrayList<Names>();
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = convertView;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.autocomplete_item, parent, false);
        }
        Names names = items.get(position);
        if (names != null) {
            TextView lblName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_name);
            if (lblName != null)
                lblName.setText(names.name);
        }
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return nameFilter;
    }

    /**
     * Custom Filter implementation for custom suggestions we provide.
     */
    Filter nameFilter = new Filter() {
        @Override
        public CharSequence convertResultToString(Object resultValue) {
            String str = ((Names) resultValue).name;
            return str;
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            if (constraint != null) {
                suggestions.clear();
                for (Names names : tempItems) {
                    if (names.name.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                        suggestions.add(names);
                    }
                }
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                filterResults.values = suggestions;
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size();
                return filterResults;
            } else {
                return new FilterResults();
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            List<Names> filterList = (ArrayList<Names>) results.values;
            if (results != null && results.count > 0) {
                clear();
                for (Names names : filterList) {
                    add(names);
                    notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }
        }
    };
}
```

---

## SearchActivity  (or your main activity)

```
....
   List<Names> namesList =  //your names list;
   NamesAdapter namesAdapter = new NamesAdapter(
                    SearchActivity.this,
                    R.layout.activity_search,
                    R.id.lbl_name,
                    namesList
            );
            //set adapter into listStudent
            autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(namesAdapter);
            autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();
...
```

Comment: This looks very promising.

Comment: ```UnsupportedOperationException``` for the ```clear``` method in ```publishResults```.

Comment: I am having same problem can any one look into my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034523/autocompletetextview-with-custom-adapter-filtering-not-working) ?

Comment: for the first time it shows correct data. after cleaning text using backspace, no dropdown suggestion appears.

Comment: Use addAll() instead of add() in `publishResults` for better performance.

Answer (score 7):

Here is a simpler, Kotlin version of what @Caffe Latte posted.

You don't need the custom layout file, just use the default `android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1`.

Provide any class to this adapter, including plain ol' Strings. It will simply use `toString()` to determine the display text.

```
import android.content.Context
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.Filter
import androidx.annotation.IdRes
import androidx.annotation.LayoutRes
import java.util.*

class AutoCompleteAdapter(
        context: Context,
        @LayoutRes resource: Int,
        @IdRes textViewResourceId: Int = 0,
        internal var items: List<Any> = listOf()
)
    : ArrayAdapter<Any>(context, resource, textViewResourceId, items) {


    internal var tempItems: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()
    internal var suggestions: MutableList<Any> = mutableListOf()

    /**
     * Custom Filter implementation for custom suggestions we provide.
     */
    private var filter: Filter = object : Filter() {

        override fun performFiltering(constraint: CharSequence?): FilterResults {
            return if (constraint != null) {
                suggestions.clear()
                tempItems.forEach {
                    if (it.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(constraint.toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()))) {
                        suggestions.add(it)
                    }
                }

                val filterResults = FilterResults()
                filterResults.values = suggestions
                filterResults.count = suggestions.size
                filterResults
            } else {
                FilterResults()
            }
        }

        override fun publishResults(constraint: CharSequence?, results: FilterResults) {
            val filterList = results.values as? List<Any>
            if (results.count > 0) {
                clear()
                filterList?.forEach {
                    add(it)
                }.also {
                    notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
            }
        }
    }

    init {
        tempItems = items.toMutableList()
        suggestions = ArrayList()
    }

    override fun getFilter(): Filter {
        return filter
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible.

*First way:*

You should create a custom Adapter which implements [ListAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListAdapter.html) and [Filterable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filterable.html).

The [Filter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Filter.html) than can implement your "contains" filter logic.

And you set this adapter as the adapter to your AutoCompleteTextView.

*Second way:*

If you're already using [ArrayAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html). You could just override it's [getFilter()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getFilter%28%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

Just to expand on the nice answer of Caffe Latte:

1)`autoCompleteTextView.showDropDown();` is not needed.

2)To retrieve the input object one can use:

```
//retrieve the input in the autoCompleteTextView
        autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            //parent The AdapterView where the click happened.
            //view The view within the AdapterView that was clicked (this will be a view provided by the adapter)
            //position The position of the view in the adapter
            //id The row id of the item that was clicked.
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long rowId) {
                String selection =parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
                Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),"" + selection,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

The object retrieved from parent must have a toString() method implemented.

Answer (score 0):

// try this

```
autoCompleteText.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {
        YourCustomModel YourFilterdSelectedModel = (YourCustomModel) adapterView.getItemAtPosition(position);
        autoCompleteText.setText(str);
    }
});
```

£
This worked for me

Answer (score 0):

This works just fine for me. I was using a standard ArrayAdapter for 4 AutoCompleteTextView's. This uses STARTS-WITH logic by default. I wanted to change just one of them to CONTAINS logic. Here is the code that works.

The old code was simply what is in the ELSE block; the new code is in the IF block for the one view I wanted to use Starts-With. The private class ContainsArrayAdapater... follows below.

```
        ArrayAdapter<String> dropdownAdapter;

        if (autoCompleteTextView.getId() == R.id.HotspotList) {
            // Create new adapter which uses CONTAINS searching instead of STARTS-WITH. 14-Aug-2023
            dropdownAdapter = new ContainsArrayAdapter(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_dropdown_item, (ArrayList<String>) adapterList);
        } else {
            // Create new adapter for dropdown layout using default STARTS-WITH searching.
            dropdownAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_dropdown_item, adapterList);
        }

        // Set Adapter on AutoCompleteTextView
        autoCompleteTextView.setAdapter(dropdownAdapter);
```

Here is the ArrayAdapter extension private class that is referenced above.

```
private class ContainsArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

    private List<String> originalList;
    private List<String> filteredList;
    public ContainsArrayAdapter(@NonNull Context context, int resource, @NonNull ArrayList<String> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        this.originalList = new ArrayList<>(objects);
        this.filteredList = new ArrayList<>(objects);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Filter getFilter() {
        return new Filter() {
            @Override
            protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence charSequence) {
                FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
                if (charSequence == null || charSequence.length() == 0) {
                    filterResults.values = originalList;
                    filterResults.count = originalList.size();
                } else {
                    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (String item : originalList) {
                        if (item.toLowerCase().contains(charSequence.toString().toLowerCase())) {
                            tempList.add(item);
                        }
                    }
                    filterResults.values = tempList;
                    filterResults.count = tempList.size();
                }
                return filterResults;
            }

            @Override
            protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults filterResults) {
                filteredList = (List<String>) filterResults.values;
                clear();
                addAll(filteredList);
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        };
    }
```

Quite simple. I haven't found any problems in testing.

Comment: Update: Please note that this is Java and I did not wrap my TextView for the dropdown list in a Layout view. Not sure why others were doing this.