# Android multiautocomplete textview suggestion with any letter

Tags: java, android, autocomplete, android-edittext, multiautocompletetextview

I am having a array list with names of fruit (for example).
I have Edittext in layout and I want to use Multiautocomplete feature into it. When I use multiautocomplete textview then the suggestions are shown only when the first letters matches the array list.

Eq. When I type "app" then I get suggestion for apple, but I want that even when I type in "le" I get suggestion for apple.

Thankyou

Comment: You can refer to my answer at the following link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32926034/autocompletetextview-not-completing-words-inside-parentheses/32928446#32928446, it's for autocompletetextview, however I think it also works for multiautocompletetextview

Answer (score 0):

Can you post some code as that will help narrow down what your are trying to do.
From what I understand you need to check if the search string is a substring of any item in the arraylist.

You can use something like arraylistitem.contains(searchstring) to filter and then populate your search results.